# If $\frac{m^{(x^2)}}{m^{(y^2)}}=m^{10}$ and $x+y=5$, then what is the value of $x-y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Given that $$\frac {m^{(x^2)}}{m^{(y^2)}}=m^{10}\quad \text{and}\quad x+y=5$$

what is the value of $x-y$?

Since both of the bases are the same, I subtracted m2 from m2 and made that equal to m^10, Since all of the bases are the same, I removed them and factored everything down to (x+y)(x-y)=10. Since we know (x+y)=5 I substituted and subtracted. My final answer was 5. I just wanted clarification if this was the correct answer

Comment: What is x2 and y2? Is that $x^2$ and $y^2$?

Comment: x2 and y2 is x^2 and y^2

Comment: Use [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help with putting things into mathjax.

Comment: Also, you should explain what you've attempted. The point of the site isn't to just hand you the solutions. You should show us that you've made an effort before coming here.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining what you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression in this regard, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: My apologies, this is my first time on this website. Since both of the bases are the same, I subtracted m2 from m2 and made that equal to m^10, Since all of the bases are the same, I removed them and factored everything down to (x+y)(x-y)=10. Since we know (x+y)=5 I substituted and subtracted. My final answer was 5. I just wanted clarification if this was the correct answer/

Comment: If both $(x+y)$ and $(x-y)=5$ then $(x+y)(x-y)=25$, so that is not correct.

Comment: @RagSwag: Your thought process starts out well, but your final result is incorrect. In any case, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3762437/edit) to include your work. Comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: Nitpick.  If $m = 1$ (or $-1$) then $m^{x^2 - y^2} =m^{10}$ does not means $x^2 - y^2 =10$.  (But if $m \ne \pm 1$ it does.)

Comment: @nitpick. Since both bases are M, couldn't you just cross out the bases?

Answer (score 4):

This is my first time using this site, so please forgive me if I am doing something wrong.

By the rules of exponents $m^{x^2-y^2}=m^{10}$, so $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=10$. Since $x+y=5$, $x-y=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, look here
\begin{align*}
&~\frac{m^{x^{2}}}{m^{y^{2}}} = m^{10}\\
\implies &~m^{x^{2}-y^{2}} = m^{10} \\
\implies &~ x^2 - y^2 = 10\\
\implies &~5\cdot(x - y) = 10\quad \text{as } (x + y) = 5\\
\implies &~ (x - y) = 2
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, I just made a mistake. I subtracted 5 instead of dividing.